# Using Realm With Existing Class?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Generic question about integrating Realm with an existing project. Another framework I have has a `User` class which has a bunch of properties. Is there anyway with Realm that I can just store this object without creating an entire new Realm model and copying over the values from the `User`'s properties to the new Realm model?

Can I do something like this?

```
class RealmUser: Object {
    dynamic user: User?
}
```

Even though user isn't a Realm defined model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Realm only supports the following property types: `Bool`, `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Double`, `Float`, `String`, `NSDate`, and `NSData`.

So you cannot simply add your `User` object to a Realm. If your `User` class implements `NSCoding` you could convert the `User` object to a `NSData` object and store that, but you would lose the ability to query `User`'s properties so IMHO that is not a practical option.

If you really want to use Realm I think there is no other way but to create a `RealmUser` object with all the properties from the `User` class. You can add a convenience initializer that makes the creation of `RealmUser` objects easier in other parts of your code base:

```
class RealmUser: Object {
   dynamic var userId = 0
   dynamic var name = ""
   ...

   convenience init(withUser user: User) {
        self.init()
        userId = user.id
        name = user.name
        ...
   }
}
```

This is not as short and practical as your solution would be, but adding custom classes to Realm is just not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Makes sense. So would you suggest going about it using Realm? Or another framework that supports what I need? And if the latter, what framework would you suggest?

Comment: Personally I've used Realm now in a couple of projects and I really like it. I doubt that there is a database framework that supports storing of custom objects out of the box but let me know if you find one.